# how to open text in webpage as link by right click "Go to web address" in new tab

Tags: browser, opera

This is related to Opera browser

when browsing some pages we see some links display as normal text,

for example google.com

so if I want to visit the web page by this link, I select the text, right click then "Go to web address".

The problem is that Opera opens the link in current tab.

my question, is there any way to open selected text in new tab in Opera ?

### Solution

after opening popup menu by right click with mouse, hold Control key while clicking "Go to web address".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold 'Ctrl' key when clicking on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Linkify](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/linkify/?display=en) extension.

It will change appropriate texts in a page to *clickable links*, so you may click on them with the *middle* mouse button (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click) to open it on the *new tab*.